# Javascript Stopwatch not working

Tags: javascript

I have a stopwatch that must call setInterval and increase a variable every millisecond, so that I get the ElapsedTime when I call Stop().
This I will use to measure the time necessary for  a request, but for the sake of simplicity i just added a sleep function

```
   function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}


var Stopwatch = 
{
    ElapsedTime: 0,
    CounterId :0, 

    IncrementElapsedTime:function(){
            this.ElapsedTime++;
            console.log("incremented to: " + this.ElapsedTime);    
    },

    Start: function(){
        this.CounterId = setInterval(this.IncrementElapsedTime(), 1);
    },


    Stop: function(){
        clearInterval(this.CounterId);
    }
}

Stopwatch.Start();

sleep(500);

Stopwatch.Stop();
console.log("final result: " + Stopwatch.ElapsedTime);
```

I expect that since I waited 500 milliseconds, the ElapsedTime after calling Stop is exactly that, 500. But the ElapsedTime just shows 1 instead of 500. What do I do wrong? Thanks

--

Explanation - after reading the comments i understood that my intention is simlpy not clear - all I want is to get an elapsed time, in milliseconds, between the interval start and clear. Can someone point me in the right direction is this code is not the best way to do this, thanks

Comment: So what is your exact problem?

Comment: Why is `500` wrong exactly? I mean you wait 500 milliseconds between the start and the stop... Also can you provide an example, [I'm not getting that result in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsb4abxg/). What is the result your getting?

Comment: @bgse it says under the code what my problem is

Comment: I explained better what the problem is now @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @Amc_rtty JavaScript isn't multithreaded, so it cannot be in `sleep()` and call the interval at the same time.

Comment: If you need to wait 500 milliseconds then you use a setTimeout() as it is only needed once. Also you shouldn't beuing a time resolution of 1, turn around on most browsers can be laggy and add 250ms, you can find this out from the internet if you look at why are timers so laggy in some browsers

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek oh  i understand, so if i remove the sleep and just use the code as is, i will get the expected result, if in between there is code waiting for a request's response to come? thanks

Comment: @Amc_rtty As long as the request isn't blocking or a busy loop yes.

Comment: @MarkGiblin please see post edit at the end, i explained what i actually intend to do, so that its clear. if what you say is right about the browsers, my code probably isnt the best browser compatible way to get an elapsed time

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek please answer question so i can give credits. apparently my problem was that i didnt knew JS is not multithreaded so the code actually worked if the long running function isnt blocking the thread like sleep does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to JavaScript being only sequentially single threaded and not multi-threaded. This means that while the busy loop `sleep()` is running, there cannot be any calls from `setInterval`, which leads to it being only called once before `.Stop()` is called.

As long as the elapsed time isn't being stopped by busy loops or blocking execution (like prompts), you will get a correct value from `.Stop()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points to look into. Inside the start, you cannot refer `this` in `setInterval`. This needs a global reference as it executes detached from the object from where `setInterval` is triggered. Second point is the script executor goes busy with your `sleep()` and forgets to execute what you wanted to. Moreover, `setInterval` should not be used for precised applications. The following code counts only till `2646` on my browser, even though I asked to stop timer after `10000ms`:

```
   var Stopwatch = 
    {
        ElapsedTime: 0,
        CounterId :0,
        IncrementElapsedTime:function(){
                this.ElapsedTime++;
                console.log("incremented to: " + this.ElapsedTime);    
        },

        Start: function(){
            this.CounterId = setInterval(function(){Stopwatch.IncrementElapsedTime();}, 1);
        },


        Stop: function(){
            clearInterval(this.CounterId);
        }
    }

    Stopwatch.Start();
    setTimeout(function() {
        Stopwatch.Stop();
        console.log("final result: " + Stopwatch.ElapsedTime);
    }, 10000);
```